# how to release "delegate" memories in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

For my project,am creating delegate class. When i assign obj.delegate = self, [self retainCount] get increased by one. So that assigned object having retain count is 2. how should release delegate object and assigned object retaincount is 1?

Regards
Srini

Answer (score 8):

It's the normal convention that delegates are not retained.  This is mainly because the usual pattern is that the owner of the object is often also its delegate and if the delegate were retained, you'd get a retain cycle.

If you are using a property, declare it like this:

```
@property (assign) DelegateType delegate; // replace "DelegateType" with whatever type you need
```

And remove the line in `-dealloc` that releases the delegate.

If the accessors are synthesised, you are now done.  If not, make the accessors assign accessors e.g.

```
-(DelegateType) delegate
{
    return delegate;
}

-(void) setDelegate: (DelegateType) newValue
{
    delegate = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Will you advise to nil out delegate to nil in dealloc?

Comment: @Chandra Patni: It is important (or was before ARC and zeroing weak references) to set the delegate to nil when the delegate object is released.

Answer (score 3):

In general you shouldn't be retaining delegates. The usual pattern is just to assign them. Otherwise, as you note, you'll get all kinds of problems with release cycles and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining the accessor for the delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Whatever *delegate;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Whatever *delegate;
```

if it is the former then the retain count will be incremented which is not what you want to be doing with a delegate. It's the responsibility of the creator to keep hold of the delegate. You are only being told about it, and should not retain it. Its only the ability of Obj C to send messages to nil without failing that means you should not be checking the reference before use too.

Comment: So before sending a message to the `delegate`it's not necessary to do something like if(delegate){<code>} ?

Comment: it's not *necessary* but you might find it useful even if the only action you take is to log the fact the delegate is not set for your own sanity